# json GPS coordinates transformation

Tags: python, json, coordinates

I need to transform some GPS coordinates in a huge json file, here an excerpt:

```
{    "latitudeE7" : 514599871,
"longitudeE7" : -984786},
{    "latitudeE7" : 514599390,
"longitudeE7" : -985072},
{    "latitudeE7" : 514599390,
"longitudeE7" : -985072}
```

Specifically, each coordinate has to be divided by 10^7. I wanted to import it in python and do it reading each field, but I cannot parse it with the json library. Any advice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *"I cannot parse it with the json library"* Why not?

Comment: hmm looks ok to me ... (well once you bound it with array brackets) https://repl.it/repls/MicroBumpyKey